# Convert list of dictionaries with values of dictionary as list to dataframe python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have list of dictionaries and the values of keys in dictionary is a list which do not have a fix length.
consider the example below:

```
[{'MOS_LN': ['1e-07', '1e-07', 0, 0], 'MOS_WD': ['1.5', '1.5', 0, 0], 'R_Val': [0, 0, 10000.0, 0], 'C_Val': [0, 0, 0, 7e-06], 'L_Val': [0, 0, 0, 0], 'Features': [6, 2, 3, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0.0, 0, 0.002, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.004]}, 

{'MOS_LN': [0, 0], 'MOS_WD': [0, 0], 'L_Val': [0.003, 0], 'C_Val': [0, 4.9999999999999996e-06], 'R_Val': [0, 0], 'Features': [3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 10.0, 50.0, 9.081, 6.35, -5.586, -9.658, -0.042]}.....]
```

I want to convert this data in a pandas DataFrame that will look like:

If the max length of list is 4 for the given key --> suppose 'MOS_LN' -> max length is 4, then DataFrame should have 4 columns for 'MOS_LN' as
MOS_LN_1  MOS_LN_2  MOS_LN_3  MOS_LN_4 similarly for 'MOS_WD' -> MOS_WD_1  MOS_WD_2  MOS_WD_3  MOS_WD_4 and so on.

```
    length_dict = {key: len(value) for key, value in X_features.items()}
    length = length_dict['MOS_LNG']
    width = length_dict['MOS_WD']
    R = length_dict['R_Val']
    L = length_dict['L_Val']
    C = length_dict['C_Val']
    
    print('length : {} width : {} R : {} L : {} C : {}'.format(length, width, R, L, C))
```

I tried to find max length so I can name the columns.

Comment: Can you please show an example of the DataFrame that input should create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprehsion combination:

```
data = [
    {'MOS_LN': ['1e-07', '1e-07', 0, 0], 'MOS_WD': ['1.5', '1.5', 0, 0], 'R_Val': [0, 0, 10000.0, 0], 'C_Val': [0, 0, 0, 7e-06], 'L_Val': [0, 0, 0, 0], 'Features': [6, 2, 3, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0.0, 0, 0.002, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.004]},
    {'MOS_LN': [0, 0], 'MOS_WD': [0, 0], 'L_Val': [0.003, 0], 'C_Val': [0, 4.9999999999999996e-06], 'R_Val': [0, 0], 'Features': [3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 10.0, 50.0, 9.081, 6.35, -5.586, -9.658, -0.042]}
]

max_lengths = {key: max(len(d[key]) for d in data) for key in data[0].keys()}

columns = [f"{key}_{i + 1}" for key, max_length in max_lengths.items() for i in range(max_length)]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns).fillna(0)

for idx, d in enumerate(data):
    for key, values in d.items():
        for i, value in enumerate(values):
            column_name = f"{key}_{i + 1}"
            df.at[idx, column_name] = value

print(df)
```

output:

```
 MOS_LN_1 MOS_LN_2 MOS_LN_3 MOS_LN_4 MOS_WD_1 MOS_WD_2 MOS_WD_3 MOS_WD_4  \
0    1e-07    1e-07        0        0      1.5      1.5        0        0   
1        0        0      NaN      NaN        0        0      NaN      NaN   

  R_Val_1 R_Val_2  ... Features_6 Features_7 Features_8 Features_9  \
0       0       0  ...          1          1          2        0.0   
1       0       0  ...          0          0          1       10.0   

  Features_10 Features_11 Features_12 Features_13 Features_14 Features_15  
0           0       0.002       0.003       0.003       0.003       0.004  
1        50.0       9.081        6.35      -5.586      -9.658      -0.042  

[2 rows x 35 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked for me and I'm getting DataFrame as I expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can explode the list horizontally

```py
lst = [{'MOS_LN': ['1e-07', '1e-07', 0, 0], 'MOS_WD': ['1.5', '1.5', 0, 0], 'R_Val': [0, 0, 10000.0, 0], 'C_Val': [0, 0, 0, 7e-06], 'L_Val': [0, 0, 0, 0], 'Features': [6, 2, 3, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0.0, 0, 0.002, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.004]},
       {'MOS_LN': [0, 0], 'MOS_WD': [0, 0], 'L_Val': [0.003, 0], 'C_Val': [0, 4.9999999999999996e-06], 'R_Val': [0, 0], 'Features': [3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 10.0, 50.0, 9.081, 6.35, -5.586, -9.658, -0.042]}]


df = pd.DataFrame(lst)

out = pd.concat(
    [df[col].apply(pd.Series).rename(columns=lambda c: c+1).add_prefix(col + "_")
     for col in df.columns.difference(['Features'])] + [df['Features']], axis=1
)
```

```
print(out)


   C_Val_1   C_Val_2  C_Val_3   C_Val_4  L_Val_1  L_Val_2  L_Val_3  L_Val_4  \
0      0.0  0.000000      0.0  0.000007    0.000      0.0      0.0      0.0
1      0.0  0.000005      NaN       NaN    0.003      0.0      NaN      NaN

  MOS_LN_1 MOS_LN_2  MOS_LN_3  MOS_LN_4 MOS_WD_1 MOS_WD_2  MOS_WD_3  MOS_WD_4  \
0    1e-07    1e-07       0.0       0.0      1.5      1.5       0.0       0.0
1      0.0      0.0       NaN       NaN      0.0      0.0       NaN       NaN

   R_Val_1  R_Val_2  R_Val_3  R_Val_4  \
0      0.0      0.0  10000.0      0.0
1      0.0      0.0      NaN      NaN

                                                                    Features
0        [6, 2, 3, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0.0, 0, 0.002, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.004]
1  [3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 10.0, 50.0, 9.081, 6.35, -5.586, -9.658, -0.042]
```